# Dual GPU (Nvidia + ASPEED) extended desktop configuration help Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, xorg

I am trying to run a multi display configuration from an on-board graphics in parallel with Nvidia card.
I am able to display the desktop on either display separately, but cannot get them to show at the same time.

Tried both on Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04.

Tried it with and without xorg.conf file.

Both cards seem to be detected by the OS, but i always see the desktop only on one display.

```
inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: ASPEED Graphics Family driver: ast v: kernel 
  Device-2: NVIDIA TU104GL [Quadro RTX 5000] driver: nvidia v: 455.38 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: modesetting,nvidia 
  unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0 256 bits) v: 3.3 Mesa 20.1.8 

xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x41 cap: 0x0 crtcs: 1 outputs: 1 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting
Provider 1: id: 0x228 cap: 0x2, Sink Output crtcs: 4 outputs: 9 associated providers: 0 name:NVIDIA-G0
```

I tried using the Nvidia prime without luck.

[Nvidia settings showing only one display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdaGy.png)

It seems that the second display (can be either one) is on but always black and i cannot select it.

Comment: "… always black …" – with, or without, a movable pointer?

Comment: with a moveable pointer

Comment: Thanks. Not Linux, but <https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/82090/> (similarly non-resolved) may be of interest.